# I need to know whether cedar is a proper noun needing capitalization

Tags: nouns, terminology, capitalization, proper-nouns, plants

I have written “cedars and Rhododendrons” and wonder whether I should capitalize cedar?

Comment: While Rhododendron aganniphum is a Chinese / Tibetan rhododendron, Cedrus brevifolia is a Mediterranean cedar.

Comment: You don't have to capitalize either one.  You might capitalize rhododendron if you are giving its Latin species name, such as Rhododendron ferrugineum, but otherwise, it shouldn't be capitalized either.

Comment: Of course, it would not be unusual to find, eg, a fancy hotel referred to as "The Cedars", making the word a proper name.  But that is an exception that can usually be distinguished by context.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find "cedar" and "rhododendron" in most dictionaries. Neither one is a proper noun.

Answer (score 0):

They would only be a proper noun if you were to be talking about a specific type or species name of cedar or rhododendron. They should not be capitalized on their own.